# Trying to access my old Drupal 6 site and getting an error

Tags: 6

A few years back i created a Drupal 6 site and due to sickness i had to leave it. Well i am moving hosting and wanted to move this site over. I tried to hit the site but get this error. I assume something needs updating but wondered is there any tricks to gain access to the panel to update this site?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ereg() in /homepages/28/d2287/htdocs/includes/file.inc:1085 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/28/d2287/htdocs/includes/file.inc(1083): file_scan_directory('themes/bluemari...', '\.info$', Array, 0, true, 'name', 1, 1) #1 /homepages/28/d2287/htdocs/includes/common.inc(2888): file_scan_directory('themes', '\.info$', Array, 0, true, 'name', 1) #2 /homepages/28/d2287/htdocs/modules/system/system.module(868): drupal_system_listing('\.info$', 'themes') #3 /homepages/28/d2287/htdocs/includes/theme.inc(493): _system_theme_data() #4 /homepages/28/d2287/htdocs/includes/theme.maintenance.inc(51): list_themes() #5 /homepages/28/d2287/htdocs/includes/bootstrap.inc(1228): _drupal_maintenance_theme() #6 /homepages/28/d2287/htdocs/includes/database.inc(176): drupal_maintenance_theme() #7 /homepages/28/d2287/htdocs/includes/database.mysql.inc(55): _db_error_page('Unable to use t...') #8 /homepages/28/d2287/htdocs/includes/database.inc(152 in /homepages/28/d2287/htdocs/includes/file.inc on line 1085

Would appreciate some pointers on what steps i should take to recover the site.

John

Comment: You've moved into an environment with PHP 7.x - it doesn't play nicely with Drupal 6. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2735435 for some potential solutions

Comment: i havent yet moved the site, so its the hosting it was always on. That must have moved PHP versions.